# app changes not reflecting while runnning docker image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am running a docker image and whenever I make any new changes inside the app folder such as in controllers or views the changes are not relfected in browser. Everytime I need to create a new image inorder to reflect the changes.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:3.0

USER root

RUN apt-get  update && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs

RUN rm -rf .idea \
    rm -rf .gitignore

ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN gem install bundler && bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

COPY . ./

# Adding a non root user
RUN groupadd --system non-root-user
RUN useradd -u 1001 --system non-root-user -g non-root-user -d /home/non-root-user -m -s /bin/bash
RUN chown -R non-root-user /app
RUN chmod -R 777 /app

# Switching to non-root user 'non-root-user'
USER non-root-user

# Exposing port 3010
EXPOSE 3010

# Default entry point (i.e. will be appened before every command being executed)
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./config/docker/startup.sh"]
```

**startup.sh**

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "Creating tmp/pids..."
mkdir -p tmp/pids/


# Start Application
echo "Starting up puma(app server)..."
bundle exec puma -p 3010 -C ./config/puma.rb
```

I have updated the below configuration in my development.rb still no success

```
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker
```

Ruby - 3.0.0
Rails - 6.1

I am running the container with the below command

```
docker run -it -p 3010:3010 -e RAILS_ENV=development  my_image
```

Comment: This is very much correct behaviour. When you build docker image it copies all the files from your directory into your image - those copies are not in any way linked to the files in your and changing the former will not modify the latter.

Comment: @BroiSatse So, if it is not linked then everytime I make any change inside app folder do I need to rebuild image?

Comment: Yes - when you use COPY. Docker images are designed to serve as deployment snapshots and such a linking would serve against that idea. However, docker has some tools that could do what you want, have a look here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host

Comment: @BroiSatse Could you share an example how can I acheive it?

Comment: First question alwasy is - why do you want to achieve this? Such an image would be only useful in local development - do you really have so many runtime dependencies to need specialized docker image to run your development environment?

Comment: I only want to do for local development

Comment: Yes I have multiple runtime dependencies

Comment: Given you dockerfile structure I'd still say this is a massive overkill (unless it's just an example). You can only use mounts when you start an image (not in the build phase) meaning you will need to run `bundle install` either on each start (Gems are bundled wihin the container) OR always bundle into a specific folder in your application using `--path` option. Additionally, if you want to connect to locally running database, you will need to play with docker network settings...